# Gaufrette list ftp files

Tags: symfony, gaufrette

I use KnpGaufretteBundle
 to connect with amazons3 / wasabi , now need add ftp.

for cloud i get list of files

```
 $uploadCloud = $this->container->get('gaufrette.product_uploads_cloud_fs_filesystem')->listKeys();
```

now try this for ftp

```
 $uploadCloud = $this->container->get('gaufrette.product_uploads_ftp_fs_filesystem')->listKeys();
```

but get

```
array:2 [▼
  "keys" => []
  "dirs" => []
]
```

folder contain files, so how list files ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i get Warning: ftp_fput(): Illegal PORT range rejected when try put, (list do not show this error)

Switch to passive resolve problem